# Calculations of different columns in Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a Table:-

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| id  | CustomerName | VideoQuality | IsActive | BufferedTime       | ElapsedTime   | TotalBufferTime |
+-----+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 139 | HotStar      | 180          | Yes      | 10.367167126617211 | 30.000000000  | NULL            |
| 140 | HotStar      | 1300         | NULL     | 5.43524230876729   | 34.000000000  | NULL            |
| 141 | HotStar      | 1300         | NULL     | 5.671054515212042  | 38.000000000  | NULL            |
| 142 | HotStar      | 1300         | NULL     | 5.045639532902047  | 41.000000000  | NULL            |
| 143 | HotStar      | 1300         | NULL     | 5.455747718023355  | 44.000000000  | NULL            |
| 144 | HotStar      | 1300         | NULL     | 5.691559924468107  | 49.000000000  | NULL            |
```

i want to calculate the columns BufferTime and ElapsedTime and insert that output to TotalBufferTime column but i want to skip the first row of the BufferTime.
So the fisrt calculation will be 5.43 + 30.000 second calculation will be 5.67 + 34.00 and so on.
I also have a column IsActive which shows the first row of Buffer time.

I want to do something like this :-

```
update RequestInfo SET `TotalBufferTime` = BufferedTime + ElapsedTime;
```

only thing i want to skip only the first row of the column buffered time.

Comment: You also need a field that determines row order. There is no inherent row order in SQL tables.

Comment: Is there any primary field in your table?

Comment: @Sadikhasan yes id field i have  in the table

Comment: @sonadas can you give sqlfiddle so I can give answer easily as per your requirements.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Sadikhasan http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/097b53/2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you a field `id` that determines row order in your table, you can use a correlated subquery so as to get `BufferedTime`  of previous row like this:

```
SELECT  t1.CustomerName, t1.VideoQuality, t1.IsActive, t1.BufferedTime,
        t1.ElapsedTime, 
        (SELECT t2.BufferedTime
         FROM mytable AS t2
         WHERE t2.td > t1.id
         ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) + t1.ElapsedTime AS TotalBufferTime
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE IsActive IS NULL
```

**Edit:**

To `UPDATE` you can use the following query:

```
SET @et = 0;
SET @ElapsedTime = NULL;

UPDATE RequestInfo 
SET TotalBufferTime = CASE 
                         WHEN (@et := @ElapsedTime) < 0 THEN NULL
                         WHEN @ElapsedTime := ElapsedTime THEN BufferedTime + @et
                      END   
ORDER BY id;
```

The trick here is to use a `CASE` expression where the first `WHEN` clause is *always* evaluated (because it is the first one) but is *never* true. This way `@et` variable is initialized with the value of `@ElapsedTime`, i.e. the value of the *previous* record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4cac6/1)

Comment: i m getting error  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS TotalBufferTime FROM RequestInfo AS t1 WHERE IsActive IS NULL' at line 6

Comment: @sonadas There was one parentheses too much. Please check the edit I made.